# Migrate app from iPhone to iPad - Not the same viewcontroller hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I have search for this question but I have found nothing, so I hope the question is not duplicated.

I have a full working iPhone app. On this app, I have two view controllers like this:
[image: MainStoryboard-iPhone.storyboard]

Favourites is controlled by `IVFavouritesViewController` and Verb list is controlled by `IVFirstViewController`. I want to do the same thing on a single iPad view controller, something like this:

[image: MainStoryboard-iPad.storyboard]

As you can see, I have two table views, also with a UISearchBar like on the iPhone storyboard. So I want to use the iPhone viewControllers on the same view on iPad, by changing them as few as possible. What will be the best approach?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you looking for a UISplitViewController?

Comment: No, because in splitViewController one of the viewControllers is smaller than the other

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a third View controller that acts like a container for the other two.  It would just have two subviews which are populated with the views from your two existing controllers.

Comment: But, if I do that, how can I set the viewController of each subview??

Comment: you may just have to code it.  I don't know much about storyboarding

Comment: Ok I will try this but if anybody has a storyboard-based answer I would prefer it